# Python Recursion Overhead

Tags: python, recursion, stack, sudoku, overhead

I have written a python program that solves Sudoku and want to make it faster. The core operation is a depth first search function which I implement as recursion. I thought I could eliminate the recursion overhead by re-writing the depth first search procedure as a loop which manages a data stack (simply a list); but it turns out that performance is not significantly different. I am pretty sure that the loop version is procedurally equivalent to the recursive version.
Is it because the data stack I use is not fast in pushing/popping? Or python interpreter really makes very good use of hardware? Can someone help me figure out what can be done? 
Profiling is attached.

search_naked is the recursive function.

```
                      2446265 function calls (1813295 primitive calls) in 4.576 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time, cumulative time
   List reduced from 31 to 20 due to restriction <20>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
709255/79779    2.136    0.000    2.136    0.000 sdkx.py:251(search_naked)
     3514    1.539    0.000    3.994    0.001 sdkx.py:106(propagate)
  3514/20    0.239    0.000    4.389    0.219 sdkx.py:234(dfs)
       20    0.135    0.007    4.528    0.226 sdkx.py:468(solvestring)
     3901    0.098    0.000    0.113    0.000 sdkx.py:82(Assume)
   467283    0.071    0.000    0.071    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
     3514    0.050    0.000    0.050    0.000 {method 'copy' of 'dict' objects}
   378200    0.048    0.000    0.048    0.000 {method 'discard' of 'set' objects}
        1    0.047    0.047    4.576    4.576 sdkx.py:487(solvefile)
```

And here is the loop counterpart - search_naked3

```
         2825303 function calls (2821809 primitive calls) in 4.367 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time, cumulative time
   List reduced from 32 to 20 due to restriction <20>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   144657    1.967    0.000    2.154    0.000 sdkx.py:148(search_naked3)
     3514    1.285    0.000    3.760    0.001 sdkx.py:106(propagate)
  3514/20    0.240    0.000    4.156    0.208 sdkx.py:221(dfs)
   443513    0.114    0.000    0.114    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}
       20    0.109    0.005    4.269    0.213 sdkx.py:455(solvestring)
        1    0.097    0.097    4.367    4.367 sdkx.py:474(solvefile)
     3901    0.096    0.000    0.112    0.000 sdkx.py:82(Assume)
   467283    0.072    0.000    0.072    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
```

[Edit]
Here attached the two functions.

```
def search_naked(Ls, LsL, Tmask, D, NLID,N, locs, masks):  #Find the smallest naked subgroup.
    #global naked, naked_mask, M_size
    LsL1, K  = LsL+1, LsL+N
    for nextLID in xrange(NLID, N):
        Tmask1 =  Tmask|masks[nextLID]
        D1=d_counter[Tmask1]
        if LsL1==D1:
            if D1 <N:
                return Ls+locs[nextLID], Tmask1, D1
            return 0,0,0
        if LsL1>D1:
            return False
        if D1+nextLID > K:# or D1>=M_size: 
            continue
        result = search_naked(Ls+locs[nextLID], LsL1, Tmask1, D1, nextLID+1,N, locs, masks)
        if result!=(0,0,0):
            return result


    return 0,0,0



def search_naked3(locs, masks, N):  #Find a subgroup in a deep first manner without recussion. counter is the stack for DFS purpose.

    counter, i, Len, bm,K = [],0, 1,0,N-1
    #i: the current index of a cell to be augmentally considered and checked with for subgroup.
    #bm: base mask is the ORed value of previously selected masks, this is used with the current cell to generate a new mask for checking purpose
    #counter: the stack structure storing (i,bm) pairs, which are used when returning from DFS
    #Len: this is a derived value, as len(counter)+1, Len is maintained to avoid calling len() function.
    #At each stage, there are len(counter)+1 cells are being combined consdered/checked as a subgroup, including len(counter) previous cells and
    #the current cell indicated by i;
    #K=N-1 does not change over the while loop; so save same redundant computation.
    while True:
        TM = bm|masks[i]       #TM (total mask): the mask to check
        D=d_counter[TM]         #D the number of ones in TM.

        if D == Len:        #That is if a subgroup is formed if D==Len<N; or we are checking the entire group (D==Len==N)

            return (0,0,0) if D==N else (locs[i]+sum([locs[c] for (c,m) in counter]), TM, D)   #return a subgroup, else, return the flag that no subgroup is found
        #From now on, D is assumed > Len. Situation of D<Len is impossible due to the treatment before the loop.
        if  D ==N or D - Len > K-i: #Current combination of cells is "blown": either N digits have be provided by less than N locations; or 
                                    #there is not enought number (K-i) of unconsidered cells that could possiblly accommodate D-Len digits.
                                    #If blown, we need to check the next cell, unless cell i is already the last of the N cells.
            if i<N-1:               #If there is a next cell, simple increase i, and continue with while loop. Len, bm should not change,
                i+=1
                continue
            else:                   #Now threat the sitation where i is already pointing at the last of N cells.
                if Len-1:           #If there is still something in the stack (indicated by Len-1), 
                    i,bm =counter.pop()    #pop from the stack to go back to one level higher, using the older base mask
                    i+=1                    #and try the next cell at that higher level.
                    Len-=1                  #Of course, the we are considering 1 less cells. 
                    continue                #continue with the while loop
                break               #If there is nothing left in the stack -> all combinations have been checked. The only exit of the while loop.
        #From now on: Len cells contributed D digits, Len<D and not blown. Prepare to go one level deeper, unless the current cell is already the last of N cells.
        if i< N-1:      #this is the situation in which, the current cell indicated by i is not the last of N cells,
            counter.append((i,bm))  # push to stack
            bm=TM                   #base mask is updated as the current total mask
            i+=1                    #The firt cell to consider in the deeper level is the one just next to the current cell of this level.
            Len+=1                  #of course, we are considering a more cell.
            continue                #continue with the while loop.
        #Now, we treat the situation in which the current combination of cells already include the last of N cells, ie, i==N-1.
        #We cannot go deeper, therefore we return to a higher level.
        i,bm =counter.pop()         # Pop the stack, returning to the higher level, recovering base mask 
        i+=1                        # and the next cell to consider in the higher level. 
        Len-=1                      #Of course, we are considering 1 less cells in the combination.
    return 0,0,0                    #The loop must be bronken! That means all combinations have been considered without finding a subgroup. Return the flag
```

Comment: The profile you posted shows that you spend almost all your time in user-written functions. Since we can't see the functions and don't know what they do or how they work, it is impossible for us to judge how to improve their performance.

Comment: Thanks. I just posted the code of the two functions.